How to avoid Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes memory configuration deadlock?
I'm specifying an Elasticsearch cluster with the elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1/Elasticsearch from Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes 2.12 CRD like
spec:
  nodeSets:
    - config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
      count: 3
      name: default
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 75Gi

which at some point leads to a situation where memory is no longer sufficient and the Cluster goes into a circuit-breaker exception state where all inter-cluster communication fails with code 429 and the infamous error "Data too large" indicating insufficient memory.
It's time to increase the memory by specifying it in podTemplate like (patch)
spec:
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      podTemplate:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: elasticsearch
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 2
                  memory: 4Gi

You can also specify Xmx in env.ES_JAVA_OPTS, but that's irrelevant to my problem that the cluster events now show that elasticsearch-controller cannot update the underlying Statefulset due to Unsupported Elasticsearch distribution: unable to verify Elasticsearch license: elasticsearch client failed for https://logging-cluster-es-internal-http.logging.svc:9200/_license: 429 Too Many Requests: {Status:429 Error:{CausedBy:{Reason: Type:} Reason:[parent] Data too large, data for [cluster:monitor/xpack/license/get] would be [1684859172/1.5gb], which is larger than the limit of [1653604352/1.5gb], real usage: [1684859104/1.5gb], new bytes reserved: [68/68b], usages [inflight_requests=68/68b, model_inference=0/0b, eql_sequence=0/0b, fielddata=263/263b, request=0/0b] Type:circuit_breaking_exception StackTrace: RootCause:[{Reason:[parent] Data too large, data for [cluster:monitor/xpack/license/get] would be [1684859172/1.5gb], which is larger than the limit of [1653604352/1.5gb], real usage: [1684859104/1.5gb], new bytes reserved: [68/68b], usages [inflight_requests=68/68b, model_inference=0/0b, eql_sequence=0/0b, fielddata=263/263b, request=0/0b] Type:circuit_breaking_exception}]}} which effectively means that in order to increase memory you need more memory.
I consider this a configuration deadlock. How to get out it?
